# Wifi not working after Ubuntu 16.04 installation

Tags: drivers, kernel, network-manager, internet, additional-drivers

I have a Dell xps 13 and I installed Ubuntu 16.04. It installed the broadcom drivers but it doesn't work. For me it's not possible to connect to the internet via cable. Is there any working solution, how I could possibly get it work.

It was working with Ubuntu 14.04. At some point, I don't know why, it stopped showing up wifi networks and didn't connect. So I fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04. But the problem didn't diminish.

At this point, I don't know what to do. I downloaded kernels and drivers and tried reinstalling, but it's still the same. The solutions on the internet I found, are not working for me.

Is there anyone, who could lead me to the right direction. I don't know where to begin.

Thx a lot

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac    Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: bcma
```

I deactivated secure boot in the bios and that solved the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: The driver is not installed.